# blur PSF modeling for small stright camera movement

Tags: image-processing, blind-deconvolution

I am interested in reovering images affected by blur of known orientation and known span. 
Camera movement during capture is very small, blur span is of about 0-4px.

What is the most accurate way to model the blur PSF? For example, how would you model the blur PSF in these cases?

- blur span: 0.6 pixels, blur orientation: 0°
- blur span: 2 pixels, blur orientation: 0°
- blur span: 3 pixels, blur orientation: 25°

I am actually interested in recovering as accurately as possible the details of the images down to single pixel resolution, so blur PSFs such as [.5 .5] and [.25 .5 .25] are significally different for my pourpose.

Comment: How to generate PSF is a question I am struggling with as well. In my system, I have a motion that I know the details (car is moving at constant speed) I need to eliminate motion blur, I couldn't find a way to make PSF function.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're able to generate the blurring PSF in a matrix form you may use the approach in [How to Solve Blind Image Deblurring with Total Variation (TV) Prior Using ADMM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75664).

Additional trick to solve the problem is to work in a multiscale approach.
Namely first solve for small images then upsacle them.